# Simple grammar parse returning no statements

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Using C# and ANTLR4, I'm trying to parse a simple grammar, which is just a simple assign statement, which would look like:
`int someinteger = 3;`.

Below are my parser rules, which contain a compile unit, block and basic statement.

```
 //The final compile unit sent to the interpreter.
compileUnit
    : block EOF
    ;

//A block, array of statements.
block: statement*
     ;

//A single statement.
statement: stat_ass;

//An assign statement.
stat_ass: IDENTIFIER IDENTIFIER SET_EQUALS INTEGER ENDLINE;
```

When parsing `int banana = 142;`, the tokens returned are:

```
[IDENTIFIER, int]
[IDENTIFIER, banana]
[SET_EQUALS, =]
[INTEGER, 142]
[ENDLINE, ;]
```

However, when printing my parse tree, it just contains a `block` which has no statements.

```
ANTLR Parse Tree:
([] [10] <EOF>)
```

Can someone enlighten me on why this fails? Apologies if this is a simple mistake, I've run out of options I can think of to fix this.

*Program.cs:*

```
using Antlr4.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace stork
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             //Test input string.
             string input = "int banana = 142;";
             var chars = new AntlrInputStream(input);
             var lexer = new storkLexer(chars);
             var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

             //Debug print.
            ANTLRDebug.PrintTokens(lexer);

           //Debug print tree.
           var parser = new storkParser(tokens);
         ANTLRDebug.PrintParseList(parser);

           //Getting tree.
           parser.BuildParseTree = true;
           var tree = parser.compileUnit();
        }
    }
}
```

*ANTLRDebug.cs*

https://github.com/c272/stork-lang/blob/master/stork/ANTLRDebug.cs

*stork.g4*

https://github.com/c272/stork-lang/blob/master/stork/Stork.g4

Comment: Please post the code that you use to produce that output. My guess is that you're invoking the parser on an empty input stream and not actually on the input `int banana = 142;`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code I'm using to get the tree to the question.

Comment: Please post enough code, so that I can put it into a file, compile it, run it and get the same output as you. If you post a shortened version of code (which is certainly advisable if your real code is somewhat large), please make sure that the shortened version still compiles and still reproduces the problem.

Comment: Okay, I've added the full grammar and program / debug file to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ANTLRDebug.PrintTokens` method iterates over all the tokens from the lexer, consuming all of them. Afterwards the lexer is empty (it's like an iterator that way), so you're invoking the parser on an empty token stream.

You should call `lexer.reset()` after calling `ANTLRDebug.PrintTokens` (or call it at the end of that method) to reset the lexer to the beginning of the input stream.

PS: I recommend calling `ToStringTree(parser)` instead of just `ToStringTree()` as that will produce more readable output (rule names instead of numbers).